# How can I concatenate .load() jquery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am using the cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-portrait-barcodescanner on my PhoneGap App.

So I can't combine the variable result and Scanner result. I have that combine this results on `.load(VAR + SCANNER RESULT);`

In javascript alert it's ok. But in Load(); not working.

Thankks!

```
$('#scan').click(function() {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {
      var irisUrl = 'http://www.vcomm.com.br/';
      $('#Load').load(irisUrl + result.text);
      alert("http://www.vcomm.com.br/" + result.text);
    },
    function(error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Did you try just saying `irisUrl = 'http://www.vcomm.com.br/' + result.text;`?

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum How is it different ?

Comment: What is `result.text`? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: [wiseacre]You can not concatenate .load() jquery method. `concat` only works for strings and not for methods and `jQuery.load()` doesn't return a string but the method[/wiseacre]

Comment: How is it "not working"? Does it produce an error?

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum 
irisUrl = 'http://www.vcomm.com.br/' + result.text;

It's ok! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to try somethig like this:

```
$('#Load').load(irisUrl, function () {
   irisUrl = $(this) + result.text();
});
```

or something like this. I'm not sure because I don't know the result of that alert in your example. What do you want to see etc.

Comment: You can't put a function call on the left side of an assignment statement.